# Best book to learn local cohomology with a global point of view

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology

Can anyone suggest me some book that we can use for studying local cohomology, with a global view to many different area of maths, i.e  to Commutative Algebra, Number Theory, Algebraic Geometry....

I have finished reading **"Commutative Algebra, Atiyah-Mac Donald"**,  **"Elementary Algebraic Geometry-Hulek"**, I also have a solid background on homological algebra.

Please help me. Thanks alot.

Comment: Local cohomology is a somewhat specialized topic, so it's not clear the book you want exists.  By the way, although they're more advanced than what you've studied so far, have you looked at the lecture notes by Hartshorne *Local cohomology* (notes on lectures of Grothendieck) and/or at SGA 2 (which is all about local cohomology, and its applications to certain Lefschetz-type problems, if I remember correctly).  Regards,

Comment: Thank you very much Matt E

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The book [*Twenty-Four Hours of Local Cohomology*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=5HgmUQsbe5sC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false)  seems to be exactly what you are looking for.
It is an outgrowth by seven authors of a summer school on the subject held in Utah in 2005.

As the amusing title says, the book is divided into 24 short chapters, reflecting the 24 talks of the school.
These chapters are extremely easy and chock-full of examples and explicit computations.
The prerequisites are at a very low level and the first few chapters will probably be a just a reminder for you: definition of affine algebraic varieties over a field, sheaves and  Čech cohomology, resolutions, limits, ...
Local cohomology is only introduced in chapter 7, in a  friendly way.

A bonus of that book is that the chapters are so well constructed that one can learn a lot of independent material from them, even if one isn't  interested in local cohomology!
For example Chapter 19 is a pleasant introduction to Grothendieck's algebraic version of De Rham cohomology; its relation to local cohomology is evoked only at the end of the chapter.
The level is  so elementary that the first section   starts with a proof of Green's theorem of  "advanced" calculus!

Comment: Dear Georges, As you can tell from my comment above, I would never have guessed that a book like this exists!  Amazing!  Best wishes,

Comment: Dear Georges Elencwajg, I have just got this book from my friend. This is very nice and I like it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, bearing in mind your previous background, I would suggest the following book:

M. P. Brodmann and R. Y. Sharp. Local Cohomology: An algebraic introduction with geometric applications.

It only requires a very basic knowledge of Commutative Algebra and Homological Algebra.